# Authentication of local Unix user using C

Tags: c, security, unix

Can I authenticate a local Unix users using C?  If so does anyone have a code snippet?

Comment: Using just traditional passwd/shadow passwords? Or PAM? I would look at the BusyBox login utility or Dropbear sshd source for concise, easy-to-read source examples. The bigger-name (and bigger-footprint) products are full of so much legacy cruft you'll have a hard time finding the code that actually matters, and you'll have to wade through several layers of nonsensical abstractions.

Comment: As written this is very much underspecified. If you can explain the use case you have in mind people might be able to help.

Comment: i am thinking of creating a local unix id, and a program would autentcaite the user input userid and pwd against the local unix ix and pwd

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good old way to do that, using /etc/shadow:

```
int sys_auth_user (const char*username, const char*password)
{
  struct passwd*pw;
  struct spwd*sp;
  char*encrypted, *correct;

  pw = getpwnam (username);
  endpwent();

  if (!pw) return 1; //user doesn't really exist

  sp = getspnam (pw->pw_name);
  endspent();
  if (sp)
     correct = sp->sp_pwdp;
  else
     correct = pw->pw_passwd;

  encrypted = crypt (password, correct);
  return strcmp (encrypted, correct) ? 2 : 0;  // bad pw=2, success=0
}
```

You will also probably need to include `<shadow.h>` and `<pwd.h>`, and `<unistd.h>` for crypt.
The whole process of calculations with hash&salt is certainly described
somewhere in header's manual pages.

Comment: this is not really a good idea because it only works for users in NIS or /etc/passwd. The more generalized solution is pam_authenticate

Comment: Yes, using PAM is adviseable. It will also avoid much other possible problems in my snippets, including eg 1] possibly swapping out the plaintext password (everyone should `mlockall`) and 2] unlikely but possible timing of `strcmp`.